# Redirecting old URLs with iron router

Tags: meteor, iron-router

i need to redirect an old URL (http://my-domain.com/details/detail-form.html) to a new URL (http://my-domain.com/details-form/) in my meteor app.

How can i define a second route like this?
This is my current route:

```
Router.route('/details', function () {
   this.render('detail-form');
})
```

And this is what i want to add to my current route:

```
Router.route('/details/detail-form.html', function () {
   this.render('detail-form');
});
```

But iron router doesn't let me assign two routes to "detail-form".

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make use of `Router.go('<your-new-url>')` in your old route function.

Comment: There is no "old" route function. The second route is the one i currently have. The first one is the one i need in addition to the other route but i cant route to "detail-form" twice. I updated my question a bit.

Comment: Then you may use same handler for both routes. Like make common function and try to call from both them and You may need to pass the `this` reference to that function. Although, It should work but i did not tried yet

Comment: Your first answer works perfectly. :) Thanks

`Router.route('/detail-form.html', function () {
   Router.go('detail-form');
});`